# Prove that pairs of numbers in a set have same parity given certain criteria

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

This is more of a clarification question.

Let S = {a,b,c,d} be a set of four distinct integers. Prove: if either (i) for each x in S the integer x and the sum of any two of the remaining three integers of S are of the same parity, or (ii) for each x in s, the integer x and the sum of any two of the remaining three integers of S are of opposite parity, then every pair of integers of S is of the same parity.

Should I break the proof up into two cases one for (i) and one for (ii). Also I tried working out the proof and am having trouble understanding it. Any hints will help!

Would Proof by Contrapositive help me here?

Comment: How can I make a truth table for this?

Answer (score 0):

First, yes, you should prove it by cases. First you should prove that (i) implies that every pair of integers of $S$ is of the same parity. Then you should prove that (ii) implies the same thing.

Second, it seems to me that these statements (both cases) can be proved directly or by contrapositive. Or in other ways. So, since you asked "Would Proof by Contrapositive help me here?", I will say yes, it can be used. That's not the same as saying that it must, or should, be used.

Third, I don't think a truth table is appropriate for this question.

Finally, here are some thoughts and hints on a proof.

**Direct proof:** (i) Pick a pair $x,y \in S$. We will try to prove that $x$ and $y$ have the same parity. Write $S = \{x,y,z,w\}$. By hypothesis, $w$ and $z+x$ have the same parity. And so do $w$ and $z+y$. So, $z+x$ and $z+y$.... (Here, "..." means that remaining steps and details are left for you to think about.) (ii) This time, $z+x$ and $z+y$ each have the opposite parity of $w$, so....

**Contrapositive:** (i) Assume $x, y \in S$ and $x,y$ have opposite parity. Now consider $x$ and $w+z$; and consider $y$ and $w+z$.... (ii) I leave this entirely for you to think about.

[The approach I hinted in "direct" could be used for "contrapositive". The approach I hinted for "contrapositive" could be used for "direct".]

**Cases:** The four elements of $S$ can each separately be even or odd. There are $16$ cases. You can analyze the $16$ cases explicitly (check which ones satisfy the hypotheses, and verify that those ones also satisfy the conclusion).

I'm not claiming that last one would be very aesthetically pleasing.

**Other:** If $x$ has the same parity as $y+z$, then $x+y+z$ is even. If this holds for all triples, then what happens when you add up all the triples? There are $4$ triples. $x$ shows up in $3$ of them. In other words, add together $x+y+z$, plus $x+y+w$, plus $x+z+w$, plus $y+z+w$. What is the total? What does it mean to say that each total $x+y+z$ is even (or, in case (ii), odd)? If we know the parity of the total $x+y+z+w$, and the parity of $x+y+z$, what does that tell us about the parity of $w$?